# Can you set a VF page for offline access?

Tags: visualforce, offline

I need to be able to access a VF page while offline. I have not been able to find away to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce supports html 5 manifests for offline access. Salesforce 1 doesn't support this, last time I checked, but your favorite desktop or mobile browser will most likely support this feature. See the Visualforce documentation for the apex:page tag on the usage for the manifest attribute.